# How to make field not required when disabled (InfoPath)?

Tags: infopath

I have one drop down which cannot be blank and it has blank as default value. I have also one checkbox with value True and if this one is ticked, then the dropdown should be disabled and allow blank. If the checkbox is not ticked then blank value in the dropdown should not be allowed.

I have my rule to disable the dropdown which works fine:

[image]

But when I add a validation rule to set it to be required only if it is blank and the checkbox is not equal to True (not checked) then it is always required regardless of whether the checkbox is ticked or not. Rule:

[image]

What am  I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your checkbox's field data type is **text** correct? Can you make sure that when you changed it from boolean (TRUE/FALSE) to text - that it matches the casing of your rules? For instance, when I changed the field to a text type, the **Value when checked** changed to "true" not "True" like you have in your rules. That may be the problem.

[image]

Thanks,
-@SharePointAP